# How to drag a slider inside an iframe?

Tags: iframe, browser, draggable, drag, puppeteer

I have an html page that contains a slider inside an iframe.

For example:

```html
<body>
  <iframe>
    <slider>
      <element-to-drag></element-to-drag>
    </slider>
  </iframe>
</body>
```

I would like to drag the slider, from left to right.

I am using the following code:

```
const boundingBoxOfSlider = await (await iframe.$('element-to-drag')).boundingBox()

const boundingBoxOfIframe = await (await page.$('.form-content')).boundingBox()


  await page.mouse.move(
    (boundingBoxOfSlider.x + boundingBoxOfIframe.x) + boundingBoxOfIframeOfSlider.width / 2,
    (boundingBoxOfSlider.y + boundingBoxOfIframe.y) + boundingBoxOfIframeOfSlider.height / 2
  )
  await page.mouse.down()

  // move the element to drag to the right (x+300)
  await page.mouse.move(
    (boundingBoxOfSlider.x + boundingBoxOfIframe.x) + boundingBoxOfIframeOfSlider.width / 2 + 300,
    (boundingBoxOfSlider.y + boundingBoxOfIframe.y) + boundingBoxOfSlider.height / 2
  )
  await page.mouse.up()
```

but it seems not working.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is `iframe` an `ElementHandle` or a `Frame`?

Comment: It is a Frame. Why?

Comment: The code for this part is missing and it might be important.